# My return is not stopping execution

Tags: java, return

I have a return, however you can see the line `"this will not print"` which shouldn't be reached after the `return` happens gets called.

What's going on?

[image: Code]

Here's the entire procedure, it's a rough copy at the moment...:

```
private void greedySearch (String lookForNode)
{
    // Note: Available vars
    // reqStartNode
    // reqEndNode

    // Search through entire tree looking for...
    System.out.println("Searching through entire tree looking for "+lookForNode);
    for (int i = 0; i < treeList.size(); i++) {

        Data currentNode = treeList.get(i);

        // ... reqStartNode
        if (currentNode.getNodeName().equals(lookForNode))
        {   
            System.out.println("Found matching node. currentNode.getNodeName=" + currentNode.getNodeName()+" lookForNode="+lookForNode);

            // Check to see if there's any children?
            if (currentNode.childrenList.size() > 0)
            {
                // Find smallest child by node
                double smallestHeuristic = currentNode.childrenList.get(0).getHeuristic();
                String smallestNode = currentNode.childrenList.get(0).getNodeName();
                for (int ii = 1; ii < currentNode.childrenList.size(); ii++)
                {
                    if (currentNode.childrenList.get(ii).getHeuristic() < smallestHeuristic)
                    {
                        smallestHeuristic = currentNode.childrenList.get(ii).getHeuristic();
                        smallestNode = currentNode.childrenList.get(ii).getNodeName();
                    }
                }

                // Check to see if smallest child by node is reqEndNode
                if (smallestNode == reqEndNode)
                {
                    System.out.println("FOUND GOAL "+smallestNode);

                    // Quit because we found the answer
                    return;
                }
                // Expand that node
                else
                {
                    greedySearch (smallestNode);
                }
            }
            // No children, we've reached the end
            else
            {
                System.out.println("We've reached the end at "+currentNode.getNodeName());

                // Quit because we've reached no further children to expand
                return;
            }
            System.out.println("This will not print");      
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Skipped node "+currentNode.getNodeName());
        }
    }

    System.out.println("FINISHED SEARCH");

}
```

**Edit:**

The correct solution I realised was doing a `return` after I call the recursive procedure like so:

```
greedySearch (smallestNode);
// Quit because we are now going recursive, our job here is done
return;
```

My ouput is now:

> ```
> Searching through entire tree looking for S
> Skipped node A
> Skipped node B
> Skipped node C
> Skipped node D
> Skipped node E
> Skipped node F
> Skipped node G
> Skipped node G
> Found matching node. currentNode.getNodeName=S lookForNode=S
> Searching through entire tree looking for A
> Found matching node. currentNode.getNodeName=A lookForNode=A
> Searching through entire tree looking for B
> Skipped node A
> Found matching node. currentNode.getNodeName=B lookForNode=B
> Searching through entire tree looking for C
> Skipped node A
> Skipped node B
> Found matching node. currentNode.getNodeName=C lookForNode=C
> We've reached the end at C
> ```

Comment: I think your code dont enter else block.

Comment: Is this a recursive method?

Comment: Show us the whole code.

Comment: It does, I've highlighted the sentence `We've have reached the end at C` which is in the `else` block.

Comment: Show us a bigger picture.

Comment: Also, look at the output of `System.out.println("This will not print, current node is " + currentNode.getNodeName());`

Comment: It doesn't enter else block but we cannot guess what was in the if statement.

Comment: You should use step by stepdebugger to understand exactly what is executed. TRy a full build of your project chances are the executed code is not the code in the editor

Comment: I've provided the full code. It is recursive.

Comment: @gbhall: You understand recursion? Run the code I've provided in my comment above, and you'll see what's going on.

Comment: @gbhall: If your first `if` is entered, but the `return` condition is not valid, it will skip the `else` and print `This will not print`.

Comment: Oh my bad, I've had a long day, I forgot it was recursive and it was going back to the previous call. 

Thank you for that line of code jlordo. It did show me what was going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing strange is going on. I can see at least one code path for which this can happen.

In a nested call, this is executed:

```
        else
        {
            System.out.println("We've reached the end at "+currentNode.getNodeName());

            // Quit because we've reached no further children to expand
            return;
        }
```

Then returning to the outer call:

```
            else
            {
                greedySearch (smallestNode); // Resuming from here...
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // ...all this is skipped (because we are in the else block
            // of an if that was true)...
        }
        // ...and this is printed.
        System.out.println("This will not print");      
    }
```

In other words, while those two lines you're looking at *are*, indeed, mutually exclusive during one call of your recursive method, they are not mutually exclusive between two nested calls. And the messages they print can appear in a sequence, as is the case in your output.

Comment: I forgot it was recursive. :) Thank you, I've had a long day.

Comment: Without thinking, is there a way to just end it for all the recursive calls on the way up?

Comment: Since this method is `void`, maybe you can turn it to a `bool` and return to its caller whether it should carry on or stop completely.

Comment: I'm not thinking, I figured it out, just add a return after `greedySearch (smallestNode);` like so:

`greedySearch (smallestNode); return;`

Quit because we are now going recursive, our job here is done